# mean square displacement on the 3-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I would like to compute the mean square displacement (MSD) for a particle moving on the surface of a 3-sphere of radius R.

I see that I could eventually use the polar coordinates and get a polar displacement for each of them, but I would like to have the displacement in units of (arc)length. Is there an easy way to obtain the MSD, provided that I know the Cartesian coordinates of the point at all time t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bijective correspondence between Cartesian distances and arc lengths on the $n$-sphere. It's independent of $n$, since it only involves the great circle the two points are on. The length of a chord that subtends an angle $\alpha$ in a circle of radius $r$ is $2r\sin\alpha/2$, so you can calculate the arc length $l=\alpha r$ from the Cartesian distance $x$ as

$$l=2r\arcsin\frac x{2r}\;.$$

Comment: I am fine with the geodesic distance. My point is that, for the MSD, one may like to measure how far on the sphere the particle has moved from its origin, eventually getting rid of the periodicity induced by the finite geometry, as one would do in a periodic Euclidean box. Is it an ill posed question?

Comment: @FrancescoTurci: I believe in its current form it is. The MSD is a well-defined quantity, and it doesn't take into account intermediate times; it's defined solely in terms of the original position and the position at time $t$, so there's no way the MSD, as usually defined, could know "how many times you've gone around the sphere" or something like that. Also in flat space the contribution from a particle that's wandered back to the origin is $0$, not some measure of how much it's moved in between. So if you want to measure movement in between, you're talking about something different from MSD.

Comment: Well, in flat dimensions, using periodic boundary conditions, one accounts for the actual trajectory measuring the MSD for the unfolded coordinates.

Comment: @FrancescoTurci: I see. I doubt you'll find something similar here, since the analogue of the boundaries of the elementary cell would be antipodal point, and you can't determine whether the particle went "through" there.